# How to find an integer from an array of integers?

Tags: arrays, vb6

Can any one has an idea about how to find an integer from an array of integers in vb6?

```
 Dim myArray(2) As Integer
myArray(1) = 1001
myArray(2) = 1002

Dim searchTerm As Integer
searchTerm = 1005

Dim flag As Boolean
flag = True

Dim temp As Variant

For Each temp In myArray
If temp = searchTerm Then
flag = False
End If
Next temp

If flag = False Then
MsgBox "find"
End If
```

I got the solution by using For Each statement , but i want the solution using Do..Loop ??

**Edit**

```
Dim myArray(2) As Integer 
myArray(0) = 1000 
myArray(1) = 1001 
myArray(2) = 1002 

'Initialise Search Term 
Dim searchTerm As Integer 
searchTerm = 1001 

'Check if a value exists in the Array 
If UBound(Filter(myArray, searchTerm)) >= 0 And searchTerm <> "" Then 
  MsgBox ("Search Term SUCCESSFULLY located in the Array") 
Else 
  MsgBox ("Search Term could NOT be located in the Array") 
End If
```

Comment: Try to loop over it? See: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?63296-VBA-Function-to-search-in-an-array

Comment: If you are using VBA, you can try `Application.Match`

Comment: I need to compare array of integers but in Filter it asks array and string? i need to compare array and integer?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Show us what are your inputs (with examples), what result do you expect, and so on?

Comment: The below one shows an example which i want                        Dim myArray(2) As Integer
    myArray(0) = 1000
    myArray(1) = 1001
    myArray(2) = 1002
    
    'Initialise Search Term
    Dim searchTerm As Integer
    searchTerm = 1001
    
    'Check if a value exists in the Array
    If UBound(Filter(myArray, searchTerm)) >= 0 And searchTerm <> "" Then
        MsgBox ("Search Term SUCCESSFULLY located in the Array")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Search Term could NOT be located in the Array")
    End If

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting it in comments because this is hardly readable

Comment: (1) `i need to compare array and integer` use CStr? (2) Why do you check if `searchTerm <> ""` if you are setting a value for `searchTerm`? This part of the If statement will never be false. (3) Instead of `searchTerm <> ""` (if you must use this) use `Len(searchTerm) > 0` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can simply:

```
Dim i As Integer, found As Boolean
Do While i <= UBound(myArray) And Not found
    If (myArray(i) = searchTerm) Then
        found = True
    Else
        i = i+1
    End If
Loop

If (found) Then Msgbox "found @ " & i
```

Comment: You need to initialize `i = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The below code works file

```
Dim myArray(2) As Integer
myArray(0) = 1000
myArray(1) = 1001
myArray(2) = 1002

Dim searchTerm As Integer
searchTerm = 1005

Dim flag As Boolean
flag = True

Dim i As Integer
Dim lb As Integer
Dim hb As Integer
lb = LBound(myArray)
hb = UBound(myArray)

Do While (lb < hb)
  Dim j As Integer
  If searchTerm = myArray(j) Then
    flag = False
  End If
  j = j + 1
  lb = lb + 1
Loop

If flag = False Then
  MsgBox "find"
Else
  MsgBox "not find"
End If
```

Comment: You need to change `(lb < hb)` to `(lb <= hb)` else you will never check the last element in the array (you should use `lb` inplace of `j` also)

Comment: Dimensioning a variable within a loop is not very efficient.